# python django self variable across the class and function

Tags: python, django

I have a view like:

```
class MyView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        email  = get_email()
        self.email = email
        return 

    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
        if not self.email in kwargs['email']
            return redirect(some_url)
        return
```

As I know assigning a value in self make is global to the class. In my get I am assigning email to the self.email that should be accessed by post too. But its now working. In post I cannot get self.email

Can anyone guide me through this ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that only one of `get` and `post` will be called at a time.

If you want `self.email` to be available in both the `get` and `post` method. You should override the `dispatch` method. The `dispatch` method is the method called by the class when the callable entry point `as_view` class method is called.

```
class MyView(View):

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        email  = get_email()
        self.email = email
        return super(MyView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you send a `get` request, it is a different instance of `MyView` than when you send a `post` request. Every request is a new instance.

Consider rewriting your methods in such a way that you don't need to store the email like this (e.g. store it in request.session if you must, but there is probably a better way to do this depending on what you're really trying to do.)